# Why are some webpages not included in Google's cache?

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I use the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4560541/170243 to link to google caches for things. However I tried to use it for http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2283129/Cameron-bans-Obama-bringing-Michelle-G8-decrees-summit-WAG-free-zone.html (which is six days old) but couldn't get it to work.

When I investigated by just googlign the header, it appeared that only the rootpage www.dailymail.co.uk was stored in the google cache, all other articles don't allow you to see their caches, although other pages that quote the article do - I'm interested in knowing how this happens and if there might be any other public caches that would do the same job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page is not cached by Google because it includes the `NOARCHIVE` directive:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir,all,noarchive" />
```

That is, the webmasters of http://dailymail.co.uk are requesting Google to not store that page in its cache.

I doubt there are other public caches that include that page, because it will mean the cache ignores the `NOCACHE` directive.